# outlook footer charset - how to use polish signs?

Tags: character-encoding, outlook, footer, polish

I have a problem with a footer to outlook e-mails for my dad's firm.
I've already manage to make it look as I want it to, but I have problems with polish signs.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
<title>www.kssssssssssss.com</title>

</head>

<body lang="pl">
<table width="100%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="width:100%; height:5px; background-color:#818285; font-size:5px; color:#818285;">Ksślłżżeęlłoó Ubezpieczenia</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="color: #818285; padding:5px;" align="center">   

        <td width="20%"></td>
        <td align="right" width="24%">
                <div style="text-align:left; width:180px; right:0%; color:#818285;">

                <a style="color:#818285; text-decoration:none;" href="http://krSssssssssssss.com/o-nas" target="_blank">Marcjusz Ksślłżżeęlłoó</a><br>
                +48 500 000 000<br>
                <a style="color:#818285; text-decoration:none;" href="mailto:marcjusz@kSsssss.com">marcjusz@ssssssssssssss.com</a>
                </div>

        </td>    

        <td align="center" width="4%" style="font-size:2em; color:#818285;"></td>

        <td align="left" width="52%">
            <a style="color:#818285; text-decoration:none; border:none;" href="http://sssssssssss.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://ssssssssssss.pl/tem/logo-poziom300.jpg"></a>
        </td>

    </tr>


    <tr><td colspan="4" style="font-size:11px; background-color:#818285; color:#FFF;    text-align:center; padding: 5px; ">
        <span> sślłżżeęlłoó Ubezpieczenia Sp.J. &nbsp;|&nbsp; 31-475 Krak&oacute;w ul. STREET 1 &nbsp;|&nbsp; 32-700 Bochnia ul. STREET 2 &nbsp;|&nbsp; 32-800 Brzesko ul. STREET 3 &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a style="color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;" href="http://ksssssssssssy.com/" target="_blank">www.sssssssss.etc.com</a></span>
    </td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here how it looks like (the bad signs):  [image: http://oi45.tinypic.com/2d1s6c4.jpg]
What can I do with that? Why it doesn't work properly?
Please help!

Comment: if i remember there are two standards for coding polish characters. you are using microsoft one (windows-1250) try the other ones (ie ISO 8859-2)

Answer (score 0):

If the characters appear infrequently (e.g., in a Polish sig in an English-language message, as opposite to a message entirely in Polish), then you could use character references when using HTML format. For example, “ś” is `&#x15b;` or, equivalently, `&#347;`. Numbers for the characters you need can be found e.g. on Alan Wood’s page on [Latin Extended-A](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/latin_extended_a.html). These references work independently of character encoding.

Warning: HTML5 drafts contain a long list of “named character references” such as `&sacute;`. They look more mnemonic, but they are a recent invention and are not supported by pre-2011 software.

P.S. I don’t know why using the characters directly fails, but I suspect that they were entered in a document using a character encoding other than the declared one (windows-1250), e.g. UTF-8. But using character references, you avoid such issues.